# enviar datos modal a jquery bootstrap4

Tags: jquery, html5, modal, bootstrap-4

Tengo un problema al enviar datos de una modal a jQuery. No sé por qué no aparece el código, ¿podrían ayudarme a editar y decirme cuál es el problema para que no vuelva a pasar?

El error que recibo es el siguiente ([captura de pantalla del error](https://gyazo.com/6b92d1a9bb7159a6fe6c26ddf6f62845)):

> $ is not defined

Éste es el código:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Jquery ui -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#formularioeditar').submit(function(e){
    console.log("llegaron los datos");
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Modal editar-->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Open modal for @mdo</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="formularioeditar">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="form-control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



  <!-- jQuery first -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- tether -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP MIN -->
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jquery para ui -->
  <script src="js/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- codigo del calendario en assets -->
  <script src="assets/calendario/calendario.js"></script>
  <script src="js/index/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El error que recibes es porque estás usando jQuery en el head (`$('#formularioeditar').submit(function(e){
    console.log("llegaron los datos");
  });`) antes de incluir jQuery al final del body. ¿Ese código lo incluiste después para hacer pruebas o es la causa real del problema?

Comment: es parte del codigo con el que tengo problemas, ya lo intente abajo de jquery y no me arroja nada , tambien lo llame desde otra pagina marca el mismo error  https://gyazo.com/41e3ecb4dddbacd75912d6bf4e512a0a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falto agregar el siguiente código y meter tu código dentro de este para que funcione:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Tu código quedaría algo así:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formularioeditar').submit(function(e){
    console.log("llegaron los datos");
  });
});
```

Intenta este método si no funciona me avisas, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Toda la pinta de que estás usando un Wordpress,

Este error es bastante común verlo allí, lo que debes hacer al principio de tu hoja JS es declarar la variable

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

Con esto estarás declarando la variable $ como la librería jQuery a partir de ahí no tendrás problema.

Puedes probar lo siguiente para ver si cargó bien:

```
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function(){
alert('asd');
})
```

Y si al cargar la página te tira un Alert es que ya te funciona JQuery en el archivo.

Nos cuentas como te fue.

Comment: Disculpa, no me di cuenta, cuidado con esto:
donde tienes esta línea

$('#formularioeditar').submit(function(e){

ese script lo debes de invocar despues del llamado a JQuery que lo tienes en el footer.

El problema es que estás intentando usar JQuery antes de incluirlo, recuerda que el navegador lee de arriba a abajo.